# Директивы import android... не видны (Cannot resolve symbol) из модуля проекта в Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Во вновь созданном проекте, в файле MainActivity.java есть несколько импортов, вот его начало:

```
package com.example.testble2;

import android.Manifest;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Build;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;
```

С файлом MainActivity.java все в порядке и все импорты работают. Проблема в том, что при создании модуля blessed в проекте, из файла этого модуля директивы импорта не видны, они помечены красным с сообщением "Cannot resolve symbol":

```
package com.example.blessed;

import android.Manifest;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.bluetooth.le.BluetoothLeScanner;
import android.bluetooth.le.ScanCallback;
import android.bluetooth.le.ScanFilter;
import android.bluetooth.le.ScanResult;
import android.bluetooth.le.ScanSettings;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Looper;
import android.os.ParcelUuid;
```

Из другого модуля с пакетом на один уровень ниже директивы импорта тоже не видны:

```
package com.example.testble2.module1;

import android.Manifest;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
...
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, что я делаю не так?

Comment: Покажите `build.gradle` проблемного модуля. Вы же модули создавали по принципу: `меню -> new module -> android library -> etc.`? Синхронизацию проекта после этого делали?

Comment: Большое спасибо за помощь! Проблема была в том, что модуль был создан командой меню -> new module -> java library, а не android library